# Google Cloud Storage pricing within Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

According to pricing note, Google Cloud Storage does not incur any fee for data transfer within google cloud, within same region.

[image: storage pricing note]

But when I tried making GKE cluster that pulls image from container registry in same region (I assume container registry uses cloud storage as backend), it still incurred download fee from artifact.* bucket. I suspect this might be because my GKE cluster and container registry in different projects.

Does pricing policy of data transfer within google cloud apply to data transfer between different projects? For example, if GKE cluster in us-west1 region in project A pull image from container registry in US location in project B, does it still incur no fee?

If not, will [Private Service Connect](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-service-connect) or [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access) make it free, by making connection private?

I researched tons of google documentation about this but it does not mention any of information I asked above.

Comment: You're missing the most import part of your screenshot: *A region is not considered the same location as a multi-region, even if the region is within the geographic limits of a multi-region.* so you will incur in costs as us-west1 != US .
Having resources in different project has nothing to do with pricing in this case and making connection private is only to maintain the connectivity within the Google Network which has nothing to do with "make it free" as well.

Comment: GCR uses multi-region buckets https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr#feature-comparison

Comment: You may need to read more carefully the documentation and also keep in mind this question is off-topic as it's not related to programming. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Puteri OK I think I was stupid. I confused dual-region with mutli-region and thought they are same thing. Thanks of catching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **`Puteri`** mentioned, Google Cloud Storage does not incur any charges for data transfer within google cloud, regardless of the projects involved. This includes data transfer between services like cloud storage and container registry within the same region. So, if the data transfer is not between the same location, you may incur charges as per the [pricing table](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-buckets), the region is not considered the same location as a multi-region, even if the region is within the geographic limits of a multi-region.

So, if the GKE cluster in the `us-west1` region in one project pulls the image from CR located in the `US` region in another project will incur data transfer fees. Data transfer between the resources in different regions within the Google Cloud typically incur egress charges. **Private service connect** and **Private Google access** enhance the security and privacy of your data transfers, the data transfer fees are determined by the regions and projects involved. Even if you utilize these services, data transfer charges would still apply.